# How to ignore regex metacharacters in an input entry array & exactly matching a string in another (partially or completely)?

Tags: c#, regex

I have been surfing for long but haven't yet found a solution.

How to ignore any of the Regex symbols occurring in mid of an entire entry, which is being used as a delimiter?

Consider the following code, where the main target is to split a string using Regex.Split, along with ignoring case-sensitivity, but delimiters could be of any size of multi-characters and might even contain Regex metacharacters:

```
    List<string> RxltOut = new List<string>();

    string[] WordsList = { "ab.c.d",  "a.b.cd", "a|b.cd.x|z"};
    string[] RgxSplits = { "cd", "ab" }; //Could consist "a|b" or "a.b"

    string RgxSplit2BU = string.Join("|", RgxSplits); //only taking into | inserted manually

    foreach (var _word in WordsList)
    { RxltOut.AddRange(Regex.Split(_word, RgxSplit2BU, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)); }

    foreach (var x in RxltOut) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
```

Currently, the collection playing role of delimiters (i.e. RgxSplits) comprise of entries like "cd" or "ab", but the said collection, if comprises any of the entries with some special character(s) like "a|b" or "a.b", would not be successful.

Had it been only a set of known entries, the escaping "\" could have had been used.

But how to take into account the combination of all entries (i.e. RgxSplit2BU) in complete form, i.e. considering only the | character for Regex added to the same manually?

If not possible, any other strategy?

Comment: You can use [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) to escape any meta character in the input

Comment: Thanks @KlausGütter.
Any advice how to apply the Regex.Escape on the said array of RgxSplit2BU, thus changing all others to simple text except the manually inserted pipe character "|" via string.Join?

Comment: `string.Join("|", RgxSplit2BU.Select(Regex.Escape))`

Comment: Works perfectly, however, the array inadvertently was referred as RgxSplit2BU.
The version found to be successful was:
`string.Join("|", RgxSplits.Select(Regex.Escape))`
Thanks again.